# Speaker works but headphones don't

Tags: headphones

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 on a notebook Asus X450C,
My speakers works fine, but, when i try to use headphones, the sound stops, but if i remove the headphones, it keeps playing normally

Comment: It may sound stupid, but on my Ubuntu, when I plug the headphones, the system automatically mutes everything so that my hears don't explode. Have you checked that? Have a look at the *auto-mute* column in `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pluging in your headphone check the system volume, it may drop itself to zero. If it is not at 0 then open the sound menu from settings, or just click sound on the the dash and change the output to your headphones. I have the same problem. It may also work in reverse headphones out and no speaker.

Comment: Tried both answers, disabled de auto-mute option as he first answer suggested, and tried to configure my headphones on the sound settings, but nothing happens.
Here is a print, when headphones are plugged.
[link]http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/295/701/full/Captura_de_tela_de_2014-06-26_22_44_11.png?1403833586

Comment: Not sure then... Is this a fresh install?

Comment: Yes, just installed ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Well I would have gone with 14.04 LTS it will be supported for 5 years versus I believe one or two more for 13.10. It could possibly solve the problem. I would try booting into a live disc or USB of 14.04 and see if the problem is solved there.             EDIT: Support for 13.10 ends in 4 days so no one here will help you. I would suggest updating to 14.04

Comment: Looks like the easiest way, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for days, but on Trusty (14.04). The solution was to do the following two things:

1. Reset user configuration (as described in the Troubleshooting section of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio);
2. Make sure **Independent HP** is **Disabled** in `alsamixer`. To do that, just type `alsamixer` in a terminal, then choose your sound card (by pressing **F6**) and move to the **Independent HP** column.

Hope it helps!