# Auxiliary port not working (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Alienware m14x laptop; it is my first experience with Ubuntu so I might be missing something simple here.

All sound works fine coming through the internal speakers (the tests work, Apps work, music plays, etc.) but when I plugged my Razer headset that I used to use with windows, nothing happened. All of the sound continued to play through the internal speakers and there was no "headphones" option in the sound settings menu. I tried everything with other auxiliary hardware too, I have an external speaker and I tried a regular set of earbuds, both of which worked fine on windows, and had the same issues.

I have also tried everything listed here [Speaker works but headphones don't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488692/speaker-works-but-headphones-dont) and here [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working?newreg=da5259fee78a45fa80177101fcb2e844) to the best of my ability. Does anybody have other ideas? Remember it could be something simple, I have had Ubuntu for a total of about a week now so I'm still learning.